# Custom NSmenuitem in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsmenu

I am having trouble using a custom `NSMenuItem()`. So far I have created a class:

```
class AllCurrencyList: NSView {

    @IBOutlet var allccyimage: NSImageView!

    @IBOutlet var allccytext: NSTextField!

}
```

I have created a xib with the two `IBOutlet` mentioned above but I am struggling to use it in my menu. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
let menu = NSMenu()
let item = NSMenuItem()
item.view = AllCurrencyList //I get the error [Cannot assign a value of type 'AllCurrencyList.Type' to a value of type 'NSView?']

item.allccytext = "foo"
item.allccyimage = NSImage(named: "foo")
```

Most of the tutorials I have found are in Objective C, and I am struggling to find examples in Swift.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

Grimxn answer was correct, but for some reasons I kept getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on (item.view as! AllCurrencyList).allccytext.stringValue = "foo"`.

To fix it I had to create my custom view in my main storyboard and create an `IBoutlet` referencing my view in the class I'm creating the `NSMenu` from. I still don't understand why I wasn't able to use the view I created in a different storyboard file. For anyone running into the same issue, [this was of great help.](http://footle.org/WeatherBar/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are trying to assign a Class, rather than an instance of the class, to `item.view` - use

```
item.view = AllCurrencyList() // '()' instantiates
```

Secondly, `item` does not have those properties `allccytext` and `allccyimage` - `item` is an NSMenuItem. You need to assign your values to them as `item.view.allccytext.stringValue` and `item.view.allccyimage.image`.

But `item.view` is still strictly an `NSView`, so you also need to cast `item.view` to your subclass, and you need to make sure that the two `@IBOutlet`s are connected properly (which I can't in Playground, so it compiles and then crashes 'cos they're not)...

```
let menu = NSMenu()
let item = NSMenuItem()
item.view = AllCurrencyList() //'()' instantiates

(item.view as! AllCurrencyList).allccytext.stringValue = "foo"
(item.view as! AllCurrencyList).allccyimage.image = NSImage(named: "foo")
```

Comment: Thank you for that, although I get an error : `Value of type 'NSView?' has no member 'allccytext'` when I try to use `item.view.allccytext.stringValue` what gives ?

Comment: Thank you for that, now I get an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on `(item.view as! AllCurrencyList).allccytext.stringValue = "foo"` I have checked that my IBoutlets are properly linked and they are ...

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why I'm getting this error on `(item.view as! AllCurrencyList).allccytext.stringValue = "foo"`. I get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` on that line...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a runtime error means that the `IBOutlet`s aren't connected properly, or at least that they aren't at the point where you are referencing them (they won't be actually connected until `viewDidLoad`...)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have tried referencing them in a separate function and I get the same error. Do I have to reference them in the class I'm calling them from ? Right now they are only connected in my `AllCurrencyList` ... Also, do I need to set an identifier on my custom view ?

Comment: I can't help much more without more code from you. The point about the IBOutlets is that there is a lifecycle in an IOS/MacOS app, and outlets aren't connected at application load, but are part of the post-load processes that happen "under-the-hood", and can't be relied upon to have happened in anything that is called before `viewDidLoad`... when are you setting them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89741/discussion-between-grimxn-and-anto0522).